# Can I apply naming rules for auto-generated code in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I can set naming rules in Visual Studio 2017 in `Tools/Options/Text Editor/C#/Code Style/Naming`.  I've created a rule to require underscores at the beginning of private field names:

[image]

However, this doesn't seem to apply to designer code (e.g. winforms):

[image]

I'd like to have the same benefits in both types of code, i.e. easily identify private fields when using them.  (Let's not debate the usage of underscores here, please.)

How can I accomplish this, if possible?

Comment: I'm not sure you can change how designer code is generated unfortunately.

Comment: Well, actually you can set the name of a control in the properties window.  I just want to catch cases where I forgot to name it with a leading underscore.

Comment: Oh I see, then it's not really the generated code you want to vet, it's effectively the designer. Does Resharper does this perhaps?

Comment: Possibly, I don't know.  I keep wishing MS would get its act together with every new release of VS.

Comment: There's always StyleCop too...